# The path alias doesn't work on https

Tags: 7, redirection, path-aliases

When I visit http://www.example.com/node/439432 on my site, it correctly redirects me to https://www.example.com/myalias.html.
However, When I try to visit https://www.example.com/node/439432, I am not redirected to https://www.example.com/myalias.html.

When I check the network, I get a 200 status for the node page.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: First thing to do is upgrade Drupal to a recent version. 7.40 is a long, long way out of date, and there may have been a bug affecting urls that has since been fixed

Comment: @Clive I understand the version is very old. But it's hard for us to upgrade it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Global Redirect module to achieve this: https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect

Comment: I have another question about the URL. I got double slash after my domain name, for example, https://www.website.com//page.html . I would like to remove one of the slashes. Do you have any idea how to deal with this? If not, that's totally fine.

Comment: There may be something hard-coded inside your settings.php file thats causing this. Look for the $base_url variable. There should be no trailing slash. If that's not it, I'm not sure what is causing it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found it. It's because of my view setting is incorrect.

Comment: oh, ok great. Glad it got worked out.